# Where perforce workspace keeps information regarding perforce [p4 info]

Tags: perforce

When i run `p4 info` in my perforce workspace then it shows me some perforce client information of my workspace. But i want to see, from where exactly it is picking up that information. I tried to google it but everywhere they are only telling about the command and it's output, i need to know the source of info for this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following items are read from the client environment (see "p4 help environment" for more information, and run "p4 set" to see where exactly each one is coming from):

```
User name: sam_stafford
Client name: samwise-silver
Client host: FORGE
Current directory: c:\
```

The client root is stored in the server database ("p4 client -o"):

```
Client root: C:\public
```

The server address is determined by your P4PORT setting ("p4 set P4PORT"), normalized via reverse DNS lookup.  The client address and client port refer to your machine and the port being used to make the connection to the server:

```
Server address: wayfarer-p4d:1666
Peer address: 10.23.2.15:54416
Client address: 10.23.2.15
```

License info comes from the server's license file:

```
Server license: Perforce Software, Inc. 5000 users (expires 2018/03/18)
Server license-ip: 10.199.2.50
```

Server root, case sensitivity, and server ID are configured globally for that server instance ("p4 configure show" will show you more about these):

```
Server root: /p4/1/root
ServerID: guru
Case Handling: sensitive
```

Server date and uptime come from the server's system clock:

```
Server date: 2015/04/23 00:03:21 -0700 PDT
Server uptime: 118:03:19
```

Server version comes from the P4D executable (same as "p4d -V" on the server):

```
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2015.1/1028542 (2015/03/20)
```